# meta-Programming Prolog ,List of ground facts

Tags: prolog, prolog-metainterpreter

I must generate a list that contains all the ground terms that pass through a meta-programming in Prolog. I did it , but the last element I don't know why is duplicate, here my code :

KB:

```
parent(aa,vv).
parent(bb,aa). 
parent(bb,cc).
parent(dd,bb).

ancestor(X,Y):- parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y):- ancestor(X,Z),parent(Z,Y).
```

Here is the meta-interpreter :

```
 solve(true,true,_):-!.
 solve((A,B),(ProofA,ProofB),Rest):- !, solve(A,ProofA,Rest), solve(B,ProofB,Rest).
 solve(A,(A:-Proof), [A:-Proof|Rest]):- ground(A),clause(A,B),solve(B,Proof,Rest).
 solve(A,(A:-Proof), List):- clause(A,B),solve(B,Proof,List).
```

My query is: `solve(ancestor(dd,vv),H,N).`

As I said previously, the interpreter inserts all ground facts in the list but it duplicates the last element. You can see it compiling my code.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last clause of the `solve/3` predicate overlaps with the previous one. I.e. it doesn't verify that the current goal that you're trying to prove is not ground. You can either add that test, `\+ ground(A)` or combine the two last clauses in a single one using an if-then-else control construct:

```
solve(A, (A:-Proof), List) :-
    (   ground(A) ->
        List = [A:-Proof| Rest],
        clause(A, B),
        solve(B, Proof, Rest)
    ;   clause(A, B),
        solve(B, Proof, List)
    ).
```

But your definition of this predicate is odd. Shouldn't the `ground/1` test be done *after* calling clause? And shouldn't you verify that `B == true` to ensure that you're using facts from the KB?

Comment: OK thanks. Putting your code as 3th line as erasing the 4th, the result list not contains all element but only 2. The query solve(ancestor(dd,vv),H,N) returns for H the correct answer but the element in H are not all in the list. The main goal is to put all elements of H as individual elements of N(List),Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
instead of your

```
solve(true,true,_)
```

put this

```
solve(true,true,[])
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this solves the OP's issue?